# Where to put business logic that spans multiple models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a situation where I can't figure out where to place this business logic.

In rails the best practise is to have fat models and thin controllers.

Now I have a situation where I am interacting (updating mostly) 3-4 model records.

Where should I put this logic?  Should I make a 'service' type class and put it in lib?

Comment: Can you show an example?

Answer (score 3):

Trying to get something to backup the evidence, [I found this](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book), chapter 1.2.3.

> lib/    Library modules

Which is definitely the most logical place to use for trans-model code.

It's basically the place where we put most of our code when writing `acts_as_whatever` gems.

Comment: IIRC, rails 3 pulled the lib directory out of the default load path - you may have to add it back.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it might be worth just creating another class in the models folder that backs to AR based models.  A 'model' doesn't have to be limited to a DB table.